# When we refresh page, it's throwing 404 page not found but page is loading in angular 13 using GCP Hosting

Tags: angular, nginx, google-cloud-platform

Angular v.13, When we refresh the page it's throwing an error in the console like 404 page not found but my page is loading properly.

It's happening to get a call, Even though we have checked JWT intercepter but it's not going with the intercepter.

[image]

Comment: Most likely this is due to improper nginx configuration, however to help further you'd need to add your current config to your question.

Comment: It looks like the page is being sent in the response but with an incorrect HTTP Status Code. Browsers will display the response body even with a non OK status code.

Comment: @IvanShatsky, current config for nginx.

location / {
   # proxy related config here that's it we have.
}

As well we have added try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; in location / object. but it wont work.

Comment: `try_files $uri /index.html;` usually is a proper configuration for an angular web app; however something else in your nginx config could break the things, so once again, you'd better to show the whole config (excluding real domain names, ssl key/cert filenames etc.)

Comment: hey @IvanShatsky, thanks for helping. the problem is resolved and the problem with nginx configuration so we have changed it.

Comment: And what were the changes to solve this problem? Please post an answer, otherwise, this question stays open forever.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe by add this code to the ***app.module*** could help:

```
{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
```